# Apache Solr physical memory in Openshift

Tags: solr, openshift

I have Solr search agent running in Openshift on a small gear as a Tomcat 7 cartridge for testing purposes.  My admin page looks like this:
[image: Solr Admin]
Why is physical memory already 99.1% and 7.1 GB. Where are these data taken from and is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Solr admin panel is showing the physical memory being used on the server as a whole, not just in your gear (linux container).  There used to be a metrics cartridge for openshift (https://blog.openshift.com/measuring-application-performance-with-the-openshift-metrics-cartridge/) but it looks like it's gone now.

Comment: It's a pity there is no more metrics cartridge available on openshift. Are there any other options for monitoring performance on Openshift?

Comment: Your best bet might be to setup something like New Relic.